# installing apk programmatically without defining the apk name

Tags: java, android

I am trying to install apk programmatically from SD card without mentioning the name of the apk. What I can do now is I can get installed the apk I named in my code. But it is not handy if I want to have another apk installed on my device and for that I have to go into my code and change the name of the apk. Is there any way to get the name of the apk file dynamically on run time? For instance getting a list of installable apk, so that user can choose which one to install?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(
Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/extsd/download   /app.apk"),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The previous code was deleted because contain errors. Here is a working code:

```
public class InstallAPKActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ExtFilter apkFilter = new ExtFilter("apk");
        File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles(apkFilter);
        Log.d("InstallApk", "Filter applied. Size: "+ file.length);

        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("InstallApk", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file[i]), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
        }





    }

    class ExtFilter implements FilenameFilter { 
        String ext; 
        public ExtFilter(String ext) { 
            this.ext = "." + ext; 
        } 
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { 
            return name.endsWith(ext); 
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:
This program simply enumerates all apk file and writes them to the array of File. After that it tries to install all this apk files sequentially. For instance, in my case I put application golddream.apk on a sdcard of my emulator. The application is developed for SDK v 10. I see the following output in my logcat:

```
12-21 06:44:39.453: D/InstallApk(14897): Filter applied. Size: 1
12-21 06:44:39.453: D/InstallApk(14897): FileName:golddream.apk
12-21 06:44:39.463: I/ActivityManager(62): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/golddream.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity } from pid 14897
12-21 06:44:40.073: I/ActivityManager(62): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity: +578ms (total +1s229ms)
```

Comment: Uri.parse(file[i].getAbsolutePath(),    "application/vnd.android.package-archive")); error under parse, it says remove argument to match parse string. and also variable i is undeclared. does it have to be class variable or local?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It was simply appreciable. There is no error in the code now. Is it possible to test the code in the emulator?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it on my emulator because I do not have a real phone )

Comment: That's great. May be I am making some technical mistake. Cause I have run the programme and insert SD card but it has not showed me the apk files. It is probably my fault some how.

Comment: As for me, I test it in the following way. Just pull apk file onto root of SDCARD and run my application.

Comment: ahaa ...ok. Thanks I am trying that soon. Thanks mate.

Comment: It just shows me the main.xml interface and does nothing. My sd card has few folders like DCIM, download (I created), LOST.DIR and the apk files. When I insert sd card emulator does nothing. Did you configure any system file using ADB?

Comment: But I did not add the code for displaying anything. This is the code how to enumerate all apk applications and install them. You should check the log file. There is a strings how many apk applications detected and then for each application in the log file you can find its name. Hope this helps.