# How to call package installer to get the list of installable .apk files?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get package installer activity in android so that I can get the list of installable .apk files and choose which one to install in my device. Currently I am trying the following code and its killing the programme.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();


intent.setClassName("com.android.packageinstaller",    

"com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there anyway to get the list or where am I making mistake?

Comment: I do not know but maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615338/installing-apk-programmattically-without-defining-the-apk-name/8615751#8615751

Comment: Actually I was the one who wrote that query too. I tried but it did not help me. As you said logcat should show me the string, even that was not happened. Hence to go around the problem I was thinking to use android package installer. but Thank you once again for you friendly approach. I am grateful to you :). But this problem needs to be solved some way.

Comment: How can package installer tell you which all files can be installed? And what exactly do you mean by installable .apk files, do you mean the files that are there on your device's SD card or something??

Comment: Actually yes. I have few .apk files on my sd card. I can install them programmatically if I give exact path. but then it is not handy if I want to install other programmes. I always have to go into the code and change the name of .apk file. Hence it would be nice if I could get the list programmatically and choose which one to install.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Maybe it will help you now.