# Android - Download and save APK files in Phone Storage (Not in SD card)

Tags: android

I was trying to **download one APK file from my server and save it in Phone Storage**.

The following is the code that I used:

```
            String apkLink = "http://10.1.20.53/files/test.apk";
            URL url = new URL(apkLink);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            context.getDir("test.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("app_test.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            fileSize = c.getContentLength();
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            int total = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer1)) != -1) {
                total += len1;
                percentage = (int)(total*100/fileSize);
                publishProgress();
                fos.write(buffer1, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
```

The same code is working fine for XML files. (When i'm downloading XML files to phone memory) .

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

---

Actually I figured out the reason,

context.getDir("test.apk", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); code line creates a directory called "data/data/package_name/app_test.apk"

But FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("app_test.apk"); creates a directory called data/data/package_name/files/app_test.apk

And I was trying to read the file from data/data/package_name/app_test.apk directory.

Anyway, Now I am going to execute this file with this code,

```
File f = new File(getFilesDir()+ "/app_test.apk");

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f) , "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

But it gives me a parse error message .

Any one can think of a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Post your logcat output

Comment: This is the logcat output,
--------------------------------------------
I/ActivityManager(  152): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/org.order/files/app_test.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity }

W/zipro   ( 8112): Unable to open zip '/data/data/org.order/files/app_app.apk': Permission denied

W/PackageParser( 8112): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/data/org.order/files/app_test.apk

W/PackageParser( 8112): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Well, you are getting a permission denied error when the package installer tries to open the APK. This is probably because the APK is in your private data area and not publicly accessible (although you say this works for XML files). You could try setting the flag Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION on the Intent and see if that helps.

Comment: You may also try using `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` when you create the file.

Comment: Hi David,

It worked .. Thank you very much .

I added Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE when I'm creating the file. 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try using Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE when you create the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615338/installing-apk-programmattically-without-defining-the-apk-name/8615751#8615751). Considering your problem I have several different opinions why it is not working.

1. Your application download apk into its private folder and maybe PackageManager do not have permissions to read this folder. Try to download application onto sdcard and run it.
2. Maybe your .apk file is not properly signed. Have you signed it with your generated signature or you export file with the default test signature?
3. If you test this on a real device check that files can be installed from other sources (not only from Google Play market)
4. I do not remember precisely but maybe to call PackageManager to install an application you need a permission.